# how to post id and password by alamofire

Tags: ios, post, methods, alamofire

all.
I study iOS and alamofire.

I tried to connect Login API url. It is correctly operating.

this is code.

```
var rTest = Alamofire.request(self.authLoginUrl, method: .post)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
        }

    }
```

and i want to post id and password

```
let params = ["Username": "ryulstory", "Password": "1234!"]
        var rTest = Alamofire.request(self.authLoginUrl, method: .post, Parameters: params)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
        }

    }
```

there are error :Extra argument 'method' in call.
the error doesn't show if i don't put params.
what is problem? could you help me?

best regards.

Comment: what version of Alamofire are you using? try `parameters: params`

Comment: @u.gen thank you it is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your backend receives and returns JSON, this should work

```
let params: Parameters = [
    "Username": "ryulstory", 
    "Password": "1234!"
]

//if server accepts and returns JSON
Alamofire.request(self.authLoginUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).validate().validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON() { response in
                switch response.result {

                case .success:
                    print("Success")
                case .failure(let error):
                      print("Failure")
                }
            }
            .response { response in
                log.debug("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")
                log.debug("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")
                log.debug("Error: \(String(describing: response.error))")

                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    log.debug("Data: \(utf8Text)")
                }
        }
```